# Bullet points appearing in navigational menu with the addition of list-style-type: none

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been having issues with adding CSS to a UL and still having the bullet points showing up.

this is my html code

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="contact_us.htm"> تماس با ما</a></li>
    <li><a href="about_us.htm">درباره ما</a></li>
    <li><a href="Archive_Video.htm"> آرشیو ویدئو</a></li>
    <li><a href="Archive_Songs.htm">آرشیو سرودها و منابع پرستشی</a></li>
    <li><a href="indexHome.htm">خانه</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
<style>
#menu {
    width: 780px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-image: url("images/Menu_Background.jpg");
           border-radius: 9px;
}
#menu li {
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
}

#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #F90;
    background-color: none;
}

</style>
```

I've read many other forums and questions that were asked on Stackoverflow and the solution was to add the `list-style-type=none; but when I added that I am still having the same issue.

here is my URL to the site http://khaneyeparastesh.com/indexHomeNew.htm

Comment: I don't see any standard bullets on that page.

Comment: It is the `background: url(images/bull.gif)` on `li a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list-style-type` is not your issue.  When you enter the code you've provided on a **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfpswhfs/)** there are no bullets.  I believe that you are referring to the red "bullet" points that are showing on your website.  These are a result of this style:

```
li a {background: url(images/bull.gif) 0 7px no-repeat;}
```

Remove that and the red bullets will be gone.

Comment: @JFA Ok good! If the answer was helpful please accept it once you are able to do so.